# Was the last part of Iggy Pop's 'Success' improvised?

Tags: recording

During Iggy Pop's song *Success*, a chorus is repeating the words of Iggy. This call-and-response technique is used a lot on Pop's 1977 album *Lust for Life*.

Towards the end of this song, this refrain seems to become increasingly impromptu, especially during the last verse:

> [[Timestamp in video](https://youtu.be/zTprPVmF8wk?t=185)]
> In the last ditch (in the last ditch)
> Here comes success (here comes success)
> Here comes success (here comes success)
> I'm going to do the twist (I'm going to do the twist)
> I'm moved, man, I'm wigged (oh I'm moved and I'm wigged)
> **I'm crazy, I'm going to** (I'm going to go crazy)
> (And if you, maybe you'd like, let's blast off!)
>
> [[Timestamp in video](https://youtu.be/zTprPVmF8wk?t=216)]
> **Alright! Baby, let's blast off** (oh, baby let's blast off)
> **Blast off on success** (blast off on success)
> **Oh you slay me** (oh you slay me, baby, ooh, you slay me, baby)
> **I'm going to do the twist** (I'm going to do the twist)
> **I'm going to hop like a frog** (I'm going to hop like a frog)
> **I'm going to go out on the street and do anything I want**
> (I'm going to go out on the street and do anything)
> **Oh, shit!** (Oh, shit!)

**Was this sequence written entirely in advance, or was it—as it sounds—improvised?**

The reason I'm wondering is that it all sounds so ...(appropriately) jolly, as if they're just having a lot of fun with it, but the chorus really keeps up well.